# Mybatis custom type handler doesn't work: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority.<init>()

Tags: java, spring, orm, mybatis

**
I am implementing role-based access control to my application. There are 3 users(Admin, Teacher, Student) in the application with same attribute so I created a basedUser entity to let them inherit it. I wished to get the user's authority when I select it from the database, so I created a type handler to convert the authority in String type to GrantedAuthority type in the process but I don't know why I keep getting this error:
**

nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating interface org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority with invalid types () or values (). Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority.()] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority.()
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2553) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.instantiateClass(DefaultObjectFactory.java:60) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultObjectFactory.java:53) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:616) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:591) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]

I have been looking for answers to this problem but not getting anywhere close, does anyone know how to solve this problem??

Entity

```
@Data
public class BaseUser {

    protected Integer id;
    protected String username;
    protected String password;
    protected Date birthday;
    protected String email;
    protected String phone;
    protected String address;
    protected Boolean status;
    protected String creator;
    protected Date createTime;
    protected Date updateTime;
    protected Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
```

Mybatis xml query:

```
  <select id="selectByAdminId" resultMap="AdminResultMap">
        SELECT a.id, a.password, a.admin_name, a.birthday, a.email, a.phone, a.address, a.status , au.authority as authority
        FROM admin a
        JOIN user_role ur ON ur.user_id = a.id
        JOIN role r ON r.id = ur.role_id
        JOIN role_authority ra ON ra.role_id = r.id
        JOIN authority au ON au.id = ra.authority_id
        WHERE a.id = #{id} and r.status = 1 AND au.status = 1
    </select>
```

Mybatis Mapping

```
 <resultMap id="BaseUserResultMap" type="com.example.abstractionizer.student.management.system5.db.rmdb.entities.BaseUser">
        <id column="id" property="id" jdbcType="INTEGER"/>
        <result column="password" property="password" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
        <result column="admin_name" property="username" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
        <result column="birthday" property="birthday" jdbcType="DATE"/>
        <result column="email" property="email" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
        <result column="phone" property="phone" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
        <result column="address" property="address" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
        <result column="status" property="status" jdbcType="TINYINT"/>
        <collection property="authorities" ofType="org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority">
            <result column="authority" jdbcType="VARCHAR" typeHandler="com.example.abstractionizer.student.management.system5.handlers.GrantedAuthorityTypeHandler"/>
        </collection>
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap id="AdminResultMap" type="com.example.abstractionizer.student.management.system5.db.rmdb.entities.Admin" extends="BaseUserResultMap">

    </resultMap>
```

TypeHandler

```
@Slf4j
@MappedJdbcTypes({JdbcType.VARCHAR})
public class GrantedAuthorityTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<GrantedAuthority> {

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, int i, GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        preparedStatement.setObject(i, grantedAuthority.toString(), jdbcType.TYPE_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public GrantedAuthority getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, String s) throws SQLException {
        return new SimpleGrantedAuthority(resultSet.getString(s));
    }

    @Override
    public GrantedAuthority getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        return new SimpleGrantedAuthority(resultSet.getString(i));
    }

    @Override
    public GrantedAuthority getNullableResult(CallableStatement callableStatement, int i) throws SQLException {
        return new SimpleGrantedAuthority(callableStatement.getNString(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type handler is not a good fit for your usage.
You should use constructor mapping.

```xml
...
<collection property="authorities" 
  ofType="org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority">
  <constructor>
    <idArg column="authority" javaType="string" />
  </constructor>
</collection>
...
```

As `GrantedAuthority` is an interface and MyBatis does not know how to instantiate it, you need to specify a concrete type (i.e. `SimpleGrantedAuthority`) for the `ofType`.